# How to pack a desktop PC for overseas travel?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, international-travel, fragile-luggage

I am moving overseas and I would like to put clothes in my PC to help the parts not move and be safe. I am worried about static electricity. I was wondering if anti-static bags will help and you said no static will be in there. With the anti-static bags help reduce static in the computer while flying? I don't want to use foam because if I use clothes, I won't have to pay for a 4th suitcase.

Comment: Interestingly enough that depends a lot on the materials of the clothing. Cotton doesn't build up static electricity but some synthetics create A LOT of it when being handled.

Comment: If you have a high(ish) end GPU, I would really recommend removing it and packing it separately. It's usually one of the most expensive part of the computer, the high end ones can be really heavy. As it's only supported on two sides, a shock like the suitcase being dropped may bend the card or damage the connector to the motherboard. The same advice would also apply to your CPU cooler if it's one of the very large and heavy ones, but it's usually held in place more securely and more annoying to remove and reinstall.

Comment: From personal experience, doing nothing other than packing the case with (mostly cotton) clothes and closing it again so that things were snug but not heavily compressed, then doing the same with clothes in a hard-shell suitcase got me through a flight with two or three connections with no problems. I think I removed the GPU and carried that separately though.

Comment: Seeing what the baggage handlers managed to do with my old machine (including seeing them throwing the box around when loading it -- the airline likely being aware of that, since they wouldn't even take it without me signing a waiver), the only way I'd travel with a desktop now would be to take it into pieces, leave the case, and rebuild it at destination in a new case. (Mind you, the huge tower is not really something to travel around anyway, it's a pain just to move it around the room)

Comment: My experience: Wrapped laptop in several towels.  Put neatly folded clothes in bottom of bag, then wrapped laptop, socks & underwear on all sides, folded clothes on top.  TSA searched the checked bag, unwrapped the laptop, threw all the clothes (no longer folded) carelessly into the bag, put the unwrapped laptop on TOP, and zipped it up.

Comment: two words - flight cases

Comment: I put clothes inside my PC case once when shipping as checked baggage.  Huge mistake.  Clothes act as an efficient force transfer mechanism from the edge of the case to the internal components when baggage handlers toss the thing around.

Comment: Luggage handlers are not touching my stuff; carry on all expensive components.

Comment: I would pull the hard drive and hand carry it, for several reasons. The amount of clothing you could lightly pack into a computer case doesn't seem like much... is that amount of clothing really what would push you to a 4th suitcase? Leaving behind 10 pairs of socks would probably save more volume than my computer case has empty.

Answer (score 24):

A never failing recipe:

1. Backup your data to an online storage, maybe more than one, and/or on an SD card. Recent SD cards have an impressive capacity.
2. Check that you can retrieve your data and that the backup contains whatever you care for!!!
3. Sell or give away the PC.
4. Travel normally
5. Buy whatever you need at the destination.

Alternatives:

- get only the expensive(e.g. video card) or valuable (e.g. the hard disk) parts with you. Antistatic bag and bubble wrap advisable, but in most cases not really needed. I do carry hard disks in my laptop bag almost daily.
- get a laptop before you leave, transfer the important data, dispose off the PC.

---

Moving an expensive and fragile item overseas CAN be done, but the risk of something getting stolen, broken or lost are usually high enough to think about the alternatives.

The static electricity is not even in the top 10 risks for an assembled PC shipped overseas.

---

p.s. if you really get to ship or check in your computer for an overseas travel, do not put inside anything that does not belong inside.

It will look too much like a smuggling attempt.

The x-ray machine operator will hate you when unable to understand what's inside.
The border/customs agent will hate you when told to inspect the box.
The bomb squad will hate you even more.
The airline will hate you for engaging everyone of the above.
Other passengers will hate you for the delayed flight.
etc, etc...

Comment: Top risks include: stuff being stolen (including personal data, use encryption), HDD getting roughed up (backup needed), contacts breaking (esp. slotted GPUs, brackets/internal foam needed). Complete PCs are shipped in crates with internal and external stabilising plus insurance for a reason, at that point it's cheaper to rebuild. If the PC is of sentimental value I would consider which parts are considered having sentimental value. Shipping the case empty and rebuilding is still simpler and cheaper than packing the whole thing. If the PC is NUC format bring it in carry-on.

Comment: As good as the intention may be, this answer does *not* answer the question.

Comment: Answer is the easiest solution for transportation, but you are forgetting that it could be impossible or very expensive to buy a new computer with same power at destination. Prices and availability vary a lot. And time consuming for custom-built machines.

Comment: **Don't** use an SD card. They are not at all reliable, as they use cheap, high density flash. Buying high capacity SD cards can also be risky if you don't know how to look out for fakes. An SSD in a proper enclosure would be a good choice, though. Also, most companies that ship computers do stuff them to prevent parts from moving around, so I'm not sure how that would be seen as suspicious.

Comment: I second @At0mic’s suggestion; change SD to SSD and this answer is even better.

Comment: With today's tech they can see everything without opening the bag, and can zoom in and spin it 360 on both axes. This includes inside the tower. I think they're very unlikely to even open it.

Comment: @At0mic My experience is different. I'm aware that experiences vary. I use reputable brand [tm] media. I have used probably one hundred+ SD cards, plus CF, TF, ... .  My exwerience has been that data reliability is extremely good. That said, when travelling I aim to have 2 or preferably 3 copies of my new data (mainly photos). I often produce around 1000 photos a day - say ~= 10GB + any videos. I retain on SD card where possible, plus copy to a netbook plus backup that to an external spinning-rust hard drive. ...

Comment: SO FAR I've never lost any photo while travelling. The SD cards also have proven (for me) reliable. I also have USB memory sticks (2 x 128 GB small metal ones on my keyring usually) 'just in case'.

Comment: I have to admit that bad SD/microSD cards do exist and I have some experience with them - included, but not limited to, silent data corruption. They were not up to the other specs as well (notably the read/write speed) so they were most probably counterfeit in the first place.

Comment: Who can afford to just buy a new PC every time they move? This doesn't answer the question and isn't practical in the vast majority of cases. If I could buy a new PC I would just buy a new PC, thank you, I wouldn't bother trying to bring mine. Nobody wants to move a desktop just so they can have access to the data, the whole point is having the hardware.

Comment: Whoever moves frequently gets portable computer. Whoever ships or checks in a desktop computer overseas generally buys a new one afterwards or does an extensive repair. In at least third of the cases a desktop computer is not universal voltage so one needs a new PSU as well.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The reputable-brand microSD in my cell phone died while I was traveling a few weeks ago. It had worked fine for years and then just suddenly died in the middle of walking through Versailles. SD cards also use some version of the FAT file system, so no journaling or anything like that, but that won't help anyway when the flash chip dies, as happened in my case. My computer couldn't even detect a volume there to try to recover data from.

Comment: @reirab Noted. I've been lucky.

Comment: ESD is very much a concern. Especially for CPUs and GPUs and to a lesser extend for hard drives and RAM. The only things I wouldn't worry about ESD with are the non-electronic components and maybe the PSU if you're feeling adventurous. Remember you only have to fry one component for the whole device to be unusable.

Answer (score 12):

Having moved my computer by plane, train, and automobile, I would highly recommend removing the GPU and the heat sink over your CPU. These are really the only pieces heavy and loosely attached enough that I would worry about breakage if you're bringing the whole thing intact. Also remove your PSU if its in the main cavity of your case and not sequestered in a separate area in the bottom (as most cases seem to do now). Your motherboard is bolted down, and your RAM and hard drive(s) shouldn't go anywhere no matter how hard everythings thrown around. The CPU (after heatsink removed) and RAM are easy to take out though, so could afford you some peace of mind to remove them and take with your carryon.

Pack tightly around the case and check the bag as fragile. Double-check all your connections when reassembling

Comment: SSDs would probably be fine (and they're light), but something like an optical drive can end up flying around (the screws can work themselves loose). And obviously, any physical (spinning) HDDs definitely don't go into any luggage you will let out of your hands.

Comment: @DanMašek this is a good point, I only have SSDs so I didn't think to mention this

Comment: In a normal computer, the power supply is bolted down at least as well as the board -- since the power supply has a metal frame, the screws can be tightened to a degree that would destroy a PCB.

Comment: Tightening the screws usually destroys the screws first.

Comment: @fraxinus, a PCB is a multi-layer sandwich of copper, fiberglass, and glue, and can be crushed by forces that a screw can easily withstand.

Comment: @Mark my experience of hundreds assembled and repaired desktop computers says otherwise. This is because the screws used in desktop PCs are crap (4.6 steel or worse) and the female threads are made in either some copper alloy or in the sheet metal openings. One can, of course, get 10.9 steel bolts and nuts and do the damage, but this is quite an effort.

Answer (score 12):

As someone who recently shipped a desktop PC internationally, I would suggest getting proper packing material for the desktop. Mine did not have proper packaging and just used various fabric items (cushions, pillows etc) to wedge the case in the box. The parts inside the case survived fine (fans, hard drives, graphics card etc).

The case itself however took a beating. The see-through plastic side panel was smashed dumping little bits of plastic everywhere, corners and other edges of the case also took alot of damage. Even the box (which was the original box for the case, I just didn't have the packing material) took a lot of beatings and was only just holding together when it arrived.

Comment: I had this issue, too. FedEx shipped my PC from the UK to the USA, and the chassis was bent out of shape when it arrived. I had to move all my parts into a new case.

Answer (score 11):

Speaking from actual experience dealing with this type of thing, unless things are actually loose inside the case, the internal components are unlikely to be significantly affected, provided that the case itself is properly protected.

The general approach I would recommend is:

1. Back up *everything*.
2. Shut down the system, then give it a few hours powered off but plugged in, followed by a few hours powered off but unplugged. This will help ensure any residual charge dissipates safely.
3. Open it up and thoroughly inspect the internal components. You’re looking for anything that is loose, wobbles around, etc. Tighten any relevant screws (‘hand tight’ is fine, you don’t need to make them so tight you can’t undo them later). If you are getting shipping insurance, make sure to take lots of pictures while doing this.
4. Place a few dozen grams worth of dry desiccant packets inside, ideally wedged in spots they will not rattle around. I typically use a 50 gram packet of food-grade silica gel for this, which you could get half a dozen of for about USD 12 on Amazon right now (these are actually useful in general for shipping electronics, so getting extras is not a bad idea).
5. Put *nothing* else in the case before closing it up. If you have a heavy, high-end GPU and the case does not provide support other than at the bracket on the back panel, you *might* consider getting a few blocks of high-density anti-static foam to brace it, but this will probably be unnecessary. Other than that though, you should not place anything else inside the case.
6. Get the required packing materials:

   - If you have the *original* packaging for the system, or the original packaging for the case if it’s a DIY build, and it’s in good condition then that is generally what you should use (it was *designed* to ship this particular system/case, so it will generally do perfectly fine).
   - If you do not have the original packaging, you instead will need a heavy box (at least corrugated, ideally double-corrugated) large enough to hold the case with approximately 2cm (much less won’t allow for enough cushioning, much more will make it expensive to get proper cushioning) of clearance on all sides, plus packing foam. *DO NOT* use packing peanuts, sawdust, or dried wood pulp for this (not only will they shift unpredictably while in transit, they *will* get inside the computer and make a mess). *DO NOT* use bags of air, bubblewrap, or cardboard/paper filling for this (they will generally not reliably cushion something this heavy). You want dense enough layering here that the case cannot move inside the box at all, and it needs to not shift or loosen up from the box being handled roughly.
7. Thoroughly cover all seams on the box with packing tape. *DO NOT* wrap the whole box. In the hopefully unlikely event that the box gets wet, the wrapping will almost never be perfectly water-tight (and even if it is, it *will* fail at some point during shipping), and it will tend to trap moisture inside.
8. If you are getting shipping insurance for this, make sure to take pictures as you are packing it, as well as a picture of it once it’s all packed.
9. Have the packaged system shipped through a *real* shipping company, not as checked baggage through whatever airline you’re traveling with. This will generally be a bit more expensive, but will in most cases *drastically* reduce the risk of it being damaged in transit, and will also make it easier to get it insured if you choose to do so.

Answer (score 9):

I'm an experienced (and old :-)) professional electrical engineer.

Removing plug in cards would be a wise precaution, but unlikely to be essential.

I would expect that the PC would PROBABLY be OK with clothes being packed in with no special attention to protection. However, the method below should be fuilly safe.

I would expect that if all clothes were packed in electrically "somewhat conductive" outer layer or bag (or bags) that there would be no problems.
If the PC is OFF and all power well dissipated (say allow some hours) then wrapping clothes in aluminum cooking foil or bags would meet this need.
When placing items in the PC,

- Hold the conductive bag and then
- Touch any bare case metal first. Then
- Insert bag into PC so it touches case metal at some point and then
- You can stop touching the case yourself.

This sequence first places you and bag at the same electrical potential, then connects you to the bare PC case metal, then introduces now safe bag into PC.

---

Ben mentions baggage being thrown around.
The risk of this can be reduced by declaring the items as fragile.
They are then handles separately - this does ot guarantee that baggage handlers do not 'misbehave' - but probably reduces the chances. I believe that fragile iems are usually NOT covered by airline damage claims - but should be covered by your travel insurance.

Comment: *"Ben mentions baggage being thrown around. The risk of this can be reduced by declaring the items as fragile."* Bwahahaha .... oh, you're serious. "Prepare for the worst" is clearly better advice.

Comment: After the abuse I had seen with checked bags, I never again put  laptop in a checked bag.  It fit snugly into a padded pocket of my backpack.  At the gate, they demanded I check it.  Instead of sliding it onto the roller-ramp through a hole designed for that purpose, the handler—right in front of me—lifted it over the one-meter high rail and dropped it onto the metal rollers.  With the fortunately padded laptop on the bottom.  If you've ever watched unloading through the plane windows, you know that many items are FLUNG into the cart.

Comment: Better remove the motherboard battery before you add foil.

Comment: I would unmount the heatsink if you have one of *those* kinds of heatsinks. You know who you are.

Comment: I will just add to the chorus stating that bags are genuinely THROWN around 99% of the time.

Comment: I have seen bags being flung maliciously by baggage handlers. And there are numerous videos of this. I will maintain my suggestion that declaring them fragile helps - they are marked accordingly AMD handled separately by the airlines.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to use foil on the off chance that some gets torn off and left behind.

Answer (score 7):

Antistatic bags are essentially [faraday cages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). That means the electric field inside the bag will be zero, as its covered by a conductive film. In order to make it work, you have to cover each component like motherboard, graphics card and all with an antistatic bag.

My advice is to disassemble the PC, take out the motherboard, CPU, SSD hard disk, graphics card and pack in the original packaging of those with antistatic bags. Then fill the cabinet with clothes and other things you want. Note that SMPS can stay, as its generally well shielded by itself because of metal casing and it itself is a faraday cage.

Finally, the motherboard and all can be packed among clothes, provided its well protected by original packaging and antistatic bags.

Comment: Hint: take good pictures of the setup and all connections before starting disassembly.

Comment: I think you're more likely to damage the components with constantly moving them around separately,  clunking around freely in your carry-on, instead of just making sure they're tightly screwed into the box.

Comment: @27701 I meant by using the original packaging box.

Answer (score 4):

I think that I would back up the hard drive to an external drive, and pack those and any expensive parts such as a high-end GPU into a suitcase well-padded with clothes. The motherboard is up to you. Then I'd recycle the bare bones of the computer, maybe getting some money for it. When I arrived at my destination, I'd order a new case to be shipped to me there.

As others hint, taking the whole thing with you intact is probably a Bad Idea. As an alternative, consider shipping the case separately with insurance.

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of travel I've done in the last 15 years has involved transporting audio visual equipment, including standard computers, laptops and desktops. We never did anything except slide the computers into their foam-lined specialty slots in hard cases. The computer always survived, from everything I can remember. Since I assume you don't have a hard case nor the time and money to spend on specialty foam, here's a few points to imitate that security while you travel with your desktop:

- Make sure internal parts are securely screwed down. I know in my own personal desktops I have in the past left cards and hard drives partially screwed down because I'm always opening them anyway. When fully screwed down,  cards, hard drives, and other parts do not wiggle relative to the other parts, and so are fully secured.
- We've never had any issue with static. If you are concerned about it, when you get to your destination plug the desktop in but do not turn it on, and leave it for an hour. That should discharge all of the ambient current from the parts.
- Pack the computer in a case that provides at least 3" for padding all the way around. Stuff your clothes there. One good hit to the side of a soft case could easily crack your mobo. If you don't have a hard case, consider putting a quarter inch plywood over the motherboard side of the desktop, then pack 3 inches of padding/clothes between them. It *can't hurt* if you feel better packing some clothes *in* the desktop. Also, you might need to, so you can take all your clothes with you.
- Plan for the worst. Back up data, pay for insurance if you don't want to pay for replacement, and expect that those gorillas in men suits *will* mistreat your baggage. The components will likely survive, but there will likely be damage to the case, like scratches and even cracks. A hard case prevents this.

Good luck, and enjoy your trip.

Comment: A side note on data backup: for all desktops we traveled with I had a cloned hard drive. I typically kept this in the computer it was a clone of, but sometimes carried on if there was valuable data. (By valuable, I mean commercially worth tens of thousands of dollars). With laptops, we usually just had extras.

Comment: With the specialized cases you use, there is no problem. I've worked with AV people at conferences. When I worked in IT for Texas, supporting field offices all over the state, we never took computers in the baggage on commercial flights, because we didn't have those cases. We would ship replacement PCs or monitors on state vehicles or put them in the back seat of a rental car and drive them there. Your recommendations are good. Plan for the worst, indeed. I could not carry my tool case onboard because of pointy things in it, and items disappeared from it when it was checked baggage.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I would just disassemble the entire PC, pack the components seperately in their original boxes, sell or give away the computer case and just order a new one at the destination. It's by far the heaviest part and likely not going to survive the trip anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you really care, don't even think about it.

Dismount your disks, travel with the disks alone and at the destination, mount those disks in a comparable machine…

Failing that, if you don't still have the original wrappaging, why not just bubble-wrap it?